# MYSQL join 3 tables but include all rows on 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a 3 table setup ( Branches, Product, and Waste ). The goal is to get a result including all enabled branches, with all enabled products and their waste for the entire week

Table: Branches

| id | Branch Name | Is Enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Big Branch | 1 |
| 2 | Medium Branch | 0 |
| 3 | Small Branch | 1 |

Table: Waste

| id | Branch ID | Product ID | week number | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 30 | 10 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Table: Product

| id | Name | Is Enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bread | 1 |
| 2 | Cream | 1 |
| 3 | Rice | 1 |
| 4 | Milk | 0 |

Ideal Result

| waste.id | branch id | branches.name | week number | product.id | product.name | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Big Branch | 30 | 1 | Bread | 10 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| null | 1 | Big Branch | null | 2 | Cream | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| null | 1 | Big Branch | null | 3 | Rice | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| null | 3 | Small Branch | null | 1 | Bread | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| null | 3 | Small Branch | null | 2 | Cream | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| null | 3 | Small Branch | null | 3 | Rice | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

SQL Query Attempt

```
SELECT waste.id, product.id, product.name, product.is_enabled waste.product_id, waste.id, week_number, waste.branch_id, branches.id, branches.branch_name, branches.is_enabled,
        mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun
        FROM `product` 
        LEFT JOIN waste
        ON product.id = waste.product_id
        LEFT JOIN branches;
```

What kind of join should be used to achieve this result?

Comment: Provide your sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: SELECT enabled rows from each separate table and CROSS JOIN these subqueries. LEFT JOIN another tables copies to this CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @Akina This is the SQL query I feed into PHP. it simply returns the result the result array

Comment: *This is the SQL query I feed into PHP.* No difference. MySQL does not know (and does not interested in) who/what provides the SQL query - CLI, PHP script or some another source.

Answer (score 2):

Frist **CROSS JOIN** two master tables (branch and product) and retrieve only enabled branch and product and use this result as **subquery**. Then left join waste table with subquery for getting desired result.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT w.id wast_id, t.branch_id
     , t.branch_name, w.week_number
     , t.product_id, t.product_name
     , w.mon, w.tues, w.wed, w.thu
     , w.fri, w.sat, w.sun
FROM (select b.id branch_id
           , b.branch_name
           , p.id product_id
           , p.name product_name
      from Branches b
      cross join Product p
      where b.is_enabled = 1 
          and p.is_enabled = 1) t
left join Waste w
       on t.branch_id = w.branch_id
      and t.product_id = w.product_id
order by t.branch_id, t.product_id;
```

Please check this **url** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4a25c2ce1f1af6729a0cfe34d8998eb6